# Laravel - return different query if query is null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

the query I wrote may at some point contain columns that are null which causes the query to return an empty array even though there is a value in the campaigns table. This is caused because the query cant make a `join` if the column values are null. I am trying to write an `if` statement to return the `campaign` even if its values are null but its still returning an empty array. If I run the query in the `if` statement it returns me what I am looking for I just cant get the `if` statement to trigger.

```
  public function getCampaigns(Request $request)
  {
    $authUser = auth()->user();
    $business = $authUser['business_id'];
    $query = campaigns::join('offers', 'campaigns.offer_id', '=', 'offers.id')
            ->join('conditionals', 'campaigns.conditional_id', '=', 'conditionals.id')
            ->join('triggers', 'campaigns.offer_id', '=', 'triggers.id')
            ->select('campaigns.*',
            'triggers.name AS trigger_name',
            'offers.name AS offer_name',
            'offers.reward_amount as offer_reward_amount',
            'offers.plaid_category_id as offer_plaid_id',
            'conditionals.dollars_min',
            'conditionals.dollars_max',
            'conditionals.dollars_more',
            'conditionals.xDays as days_since_last_purchase',
            'conditionals.xDate as date_since_last_purchase',
            'conditionals.xPercent as percentage_more',
            'conditionals.xPurchases as purchases_x_times',
            'conditionals.start_date',
            'conditionals.end_date',
            'conditionals.plaid_category_id')
            // ->whereNull('campaigns.trigger_id', 'campaigns.offer_id', 'campaigns.conditional_id')
            ->where('campaigns.business_id', '=', $business);
    if ($query->count() === 0){
      $query = campaigns::select('*')->where('business_id', '=', $business);
    }
    return $query->get();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'left' joins? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query builder get() method will not return null if no results are found, it will return an empty collection.

Check for an empty collection instead:

```
if ($query->count() === 0){
```

I would recommend renaming $query for readability too, since it's not assigned the query, it's assigned the results.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. that worked. only problem I have is that if there is a campaign with no null values and one with null values it only shows the campaign with null values. I wrote a foreach loop around the if statement but that didnt work either.

Comment: which values are null?  I'm sure that can be solved with your query instead of php.

Comment: The joined columns are null. It will need php. I can figure that out. thanks for the help with the query.

Comment: I think you should look into left joins